# What does it mean if you combine "Event Category/Action/Label" with "Pageviews"?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, page-views

I would expect the Event-Hit won't get a "Pageviews" metric, but actually you CAN combine the "Event Category/Action/Label" with "Pageviews" in custom report or DataStudio, what does it mean in such a combination??

```
--------------------------
Event Category | Pageviews
--------------------------
cat1           | 100,000
cat2           | 200,000
cat3           | 300,000
--------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some poking around, and judging by the numbers I saw, in your example, `100,000` is the total number of pageviews in sessions in which an event of category `cat1` occurred. `200,000` is the total number of pageviews in sessions in which an event of category `cat2` occurred - which may double count sessions from the `cat1` line.

When I looked at data I saw numbers like this:

- Total pageviews in sessions in which some event took place: 125
- Column total for a report pairing Event Category with Pageviews: 225
- Column total for a report pairing Event Action with Pageviews: 525
- Column total for a report pairing Event Label with Pageviews: 1350

There are more distinct Labels in our setup than Actions, and more distinct Actions than Categories, so the duplicate counting is more or less extreme depending on your choice of dimension.

So it's a valid combination, but the numbers aren't particularly meaningful.